# MaterializeCSS select not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, materialize

MaterializeCSS select with repeated options (using `ng-repeat`) is not working. Kindly assist!

```
<div class="col s12 input-field">
    <select ng-model="selected-category" id="category" name="category" class="">
        <option value="" selected>Choose Category</option>
        <option ng-repeat="c in categories" value="c.catCode">{{c.catDescription}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a similar problem.

According to the MaterializeCSS documentation, you need to initialize your select with this:

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').material_select();
  });`

You also need to call `$('select').material_select();`again after your ng-repeat is compiled in order for your select to have the correct options populated.

Source: http://materializecss.com/forms.html#select-initialization