# ng-repeat not working in materialize Select list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, materialize

I am using the materialize select list format to create a list that populates data from a database. Here is my angular/html code:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedBrand">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select the channel</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="brand in ctrl.masterbrands" value="{{brand}}"> {{brand}}
                    </option>
                </select>
                <label>Choose the channel</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I know the data is being extracted correctly because when I try

```
<p ng-repeat="brand in ctrl.masterbrands" value="{{brand}}"> {{brand}} </p>
```

All my data appears in my front end. Is there anything wrong with the way I am using ng-repeat in my Select List?

**EDIT**

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997013/materializecss-select-not-working-with-ng-repeat) I added in a $('select').material_select(); after my ng-repeat, this worked at first and then stopped working while I was testing my website!

```
                <select ng-model="ctrl.selectedBrand">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select the channel</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="brand in ctrl.masterbrands" value="{{brand}}"> {{brand}}
                    </option>
                    $('select').material_select();
                </select>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is?

Comment: Can you post the code for that please?

Comment: @PankajParkar shouldn't ng-repeat work anyway?

Comment: `ng-options` would solve your problem https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: @sums22 can you please add object of what `ctrl.masterbrands` has??

Comment: @PankajParkar masterbrands contains an array of String as such: masterbrand:[bbc 1xtra, bbc 6music, bbc 7, bbc alba, .....]

Comment: @MdJohirulIslam is this the correct syntax for it? <select ng-options="brand as brand for brand in ctrl.masterbrands"
                            ng-model="ctrl.selected">

                    </select> Because it is not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faced the similar kind of issue. Find the working code and a brief explanation below.

[image: Here is the screenshot]

Here's my working controller code:

```
angular.module("app")
.controller('demoController', ['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    var self = this;

    function init() {
        self.dialCodes = [
            {   "name": "United States",
                "dial_code": "+1",
                "code": "US"
            }, {
                "name": "India",
                "dial_code": "+91",
                "code": "IN"
            }, {
                "name": "United Kingdom",
                "dial_code": "+44",
                "code": "GB"
           }];

         $timeout(function () {
            $('select').material_select()
         });
    };
    init();
}]);
```

Materialise select list HTML code:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select>
       <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
       <option ng-repeat="code in ctrl.dialCodes" value={{code.dial_code}}">
             {{code.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

---

### Brief Explanation

What behind the seen happening is that before ng-repeat could actually finish its action, our little materialize jQuery code:

```
$('select').material_select()
```

kicks in and creates the select list.

But by wrapping jQuery code inside $timeout, it waits till the next digest cycle and then creates the select list.

and Here's the working select list

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Put the input content in select, after use the setTimeout

```
 setTimeout(function(){
        $('select').material_select();
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is a bug in the materialize you can visit [link 1](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2838) and [Link 2](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/365) for more details

The best solution for this is to use a angular wrapper for materialize.css which you can find at [Angular Materialize](https://krescruz.github.io/angular-materialize/)

Checkout the below snippet

```js
angular.module('myapp', ['ui.materialize']).controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.brand = {
    value: "LG",
    alltypes: ["LG", "SAMSUNG", "NOKIA", "HTC", "SONY"]
  };
}]);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- JavaScript for: jQuery, angular, materialize, and angular-materialize. All of which are needed. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-materialize/0.2.2/angular-materialize.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="testController" class="row">
  <div class="input-field col s12">
    <select ng-model="brand.value" material-select>
                        <option ng-repeat="value in brand.alltypes">{{value}}</option>
                    </select>
    <label>Choose the brand</label>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I already have jQuery, angular and materialize, I added the single script for angular-materialize but nothing seems to have changed..

Comment: Do you have any idea why adding  $('select').material_select(); after the ng-repeat worked for me initially and then stopped working?

Comment: Also, are you sure that is the correct name for the script, my browser does not recognise angular-materialize.min.js:1 ? Any idea how to get it through bower instead?